# Get ID of Amazon Connect - Basic Routing Profile to use in "aws_connect_user" Terraform resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-connect

I'm deploying an Amazon Connect instance via Terraform. In order to access the Amazon Connect CCP (Contact Control Panel) without using the emergency access, I need to deploy the following Terraform resource: "aws_connect_user".

As specified in Terraform registry for this resource (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/connect_user) at one point I need the routing_profile_id, therefore I was thinking to use the ID of the Basic Routing Profile that Amazon automatically creates when you deploy an Amazon Connect instance.
The problem is that I don't know how to get this information and which Terraform command I should use.

Consider that I'm new in using Terraform.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you actually read this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/amazon-connect-get-started.html?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Marko, I have already read the general AWS documentation for the Amazon Connect, but I didn't find the answer to my question. Btw, I solved it using "aws_connect_routing_profile" Terraform data source (suggested by Chat GPT).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out by yourself, going with the aws_connect_routing_profile data source is the way to go:

```
data "aws_connect_routing_profile" "example" {
    instance_id = "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-111111111111"
    name        = "Basic Routing Profile"
}
```

Documentation: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/connect_routing_profile